# Radiobuttonlist results not working when rbl's dynamically created

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radiobuttonlist

I have 20 radiobuttonlists which are dynamically created - then declared when a form is submitted.

I also have some code which totals the number of answered questions and the total value of the answered questions. - this code used to work when the radiobuttonlists were hard coded into the page, but it now does not. - I am writing the number of questions answered and the total value of all answers to the page but they come back as 0.

Can anyone see why this might not work now that the radiobuttonlists are dynamically created.?

Code behind:

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal E as EventArgs)

        For i As Integer = 1 To 20

            Dim TableRow As New TableRow()
            Dim TableRowCell_1 As New TableCell()
            TableRow.Cells.Add(TableRowCell_1)
            holidayQuestionnaireTable.Rows.Add(TableRow)

            Dim question As New RadioButtonList
            question.ID = "question" & i

            question.Items.Insert(0, new listitem("", "1"))
            question.Items.Insert(1, new listitem("", "2"))
            TableRowCell_1.Controls.Add(question)

        Next

End Sub
```

...

```
Sub btnSendFeedback_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)

    Dim question1 As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("question1"), RadioButtonList)
    Dim question2 As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("question2"), RadioButtonList)
    Dim question3 ...
    ...
    Dim question19 As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("question19"), RadioButtonList)
    Dim question20 As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("question20"), RadioButtonList)

    Dim rblCount As Double
    Dim total As Double
    Dim avg As Double

    For Each ctrl As UI.Control In Me.myPanel.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButtonList Then
            Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(ctrl, RadioButtonList)
            If rbl.SelectedIndex > -1 And not rbl.ID = "question18" Then
                Dim value As Double = Double.Parse(rbl.SelectedValue)
                total += value
                rblCount += 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Response.Write(rblCount & " - " & total & " - " & (total / rblCount))

End Sub
```

Body:

```
<asp:Placeholder ID="myPanel" runat="server">
        <asp:Table runat="server" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="ratingtable" ID="holidayQuestionnaireTable" />
        <asp:Button OnClick="btnSendFeedback_Click" runat="server" Text="Submit..." ID="submitbutton" />
</asp:Placeholder>
```

Comment: `"but it now does not."` is a fairly vague description of what's not working!

Comment: Sorry... hopefully it's a little clearer now. I'm not sure how to best explain it though.

Comment: you should also show the code where you add the RBL's dynamically(i assume to the Panel?!). It seems that there are no controls in the panel, so where, when and to what are you adding the RadioButtonLists? Are you recreating them on every postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the content of your panel and added a Table instead of using the Panel to add the RadioButtonLists directly. FindControl will only look into the NamingContainer of the Panel and not of its child controls' NamingContainer. Searching through the control-collection of the Panel does also not work because the RBL's are inside of the Table that is inside of the Panel. Therefore you have to loop the TableRows to get the RBL's. Have a look:

```
For Each row As TableRow In Me.holidayQuestionnaireTable.Rows
     For Each cell As TableCell In row.Cells
         For Each ctrl As Control In cell.Controls
             If TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButtonList Then
                Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(ctrl, RadioButtonList)
                If rbl.SelectedIndex <> -1 AndAlso rbl.ID <> "question18" Then
                   Dim value As Int32 = Int32.Parse(rbl.SelectedValue)
                   total += value
                   rblCount += 1 'count only the selected RadiobuttonLists'
                End If
             End If
         Next
    Next
Next
```

If you want to use the FindControl-approach, you have to use the NamingContainer of each radioButtonList and that is the TableRow. So this would also work, but is very static and error-prone:

```
Dim question1 As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Me.holidayQuestionnaireTable.Rows(0).FindControl("question1"), RadioButtonList)
Dim question2 As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Me.holidayQuestionnaireTable.Rows(1).FindControl("question2"), RadioButtonList)
Dim question3 As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Me.holidayQuestionnaireTable.Rows(2).FindControl("question3"), RadioButtonList)
```

Comment: @Tom: glad i could help. Notice that i've added another way to get your question via FindControl.